# What does it mean to keep accounts?

Tags: word-usage

Is this related to money? Like to keep track of how much is spent or earned. Bookkeeping？Is there a better way of saying it?

Answer (score 1):

*Accounting* is the art of keeping track of money in ledgers.  *To keep accounts* is the act of doing accounting.  *Bookkeeping* is another way to say the same thing, although sometimes *bookkeeping* can mean managing gambling odds for the purposes of betting on a race or other event, but context can usually make this clear.

There may or may not be a better way to say it in a given context.  I would need a specific context in order to answer.